# autocomplete with multiple values and automatic replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using autocomplete with multiple remote values.
Every search gives me only one word (words in input text are separated by space)

I removed return false; from focus function and now when I focus on autocomplete results it automaticly change the input text and when i return focus to input text it show the original text i wrote.

This is behaviour that i want, but the problem is when I search second word.
Then when the autocomplete search i focused it overwrites the first word in input text.

I want the first word stay the same and only second (3, 4 ..) word changes. And when I return to input text I get the original text I wrote before I focus the search result.

My code:

```
    $(function() {

    function split( val ) {
        return val.split( / \s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
        return split( term ).pop();
    }


    $( "#tags" )

         // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                    $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        .autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.getJSON( "http://test.dev/search.php", {
                    term: extractLast( request.term ),
                    complete: request.term,

                }, response );
            },
            search: function() {
                // custom minLength
                var term = extractLast( this.value );
                if ( term.length < 2 ) {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            focus: function(event, ui) {

            },
              select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = split( this.value );
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push( "" );
                this.value = terms.join( " " );

                return false;
            }
        });


});
```